# c++: how to access variables in the same namespace but defined in a different file?

Tags: c++, namespaces, extern

Consider the following two files:

a.cpp:

```
#include <string>
namespace a
{
    const std::string str = "something";
}
```

b.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

namespace a
{
    extern const std::string str;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::cout << a::str;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile them, thusly (Fedora 30, gcc 9.2.1):

```
g++ a.cpp b.cpp -o a
```

I get linker errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccEtAgEb.o: in function `main':
b.cpp:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `a::str[abi:cxx11]'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Anyone able to tell me why, and how to fix it? I wanted to avoid putting a reference to a::str in a header file, since it's not part of the public interface, but rather a private variable within my namespace.

Comment: Re: "I wanted to avoid putting a reference to `a::str` in a header file, since it's not part of the public interface": -- header files pretty much always contain information about things that aren't part of the public interface. Private members in a class definition are the most obvious example. If you don't put this in a header and for some reason you decide to change the name of the namespace or of the `string` object you have to hunt down every place where you used that name and change it.

Comment: @PeteBecker missed that, thanks

Comment: Also you can put it in a private header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const std::string str = "something";
```

should be

```
extern const std::string str = "something";
```

`const` qualifying objects at namespace scope has the additional property of imposing internal linkage on their name. Your original code is the same as

```
static const std::string str = "something";
```

Comment: If I change "const" to "extern const" in a.cpp, we still do not have a definition of a::str, and there are still linker errors. It appears that something more is still required.

Comment: On further testing, If I remove the "const" from both a.cpp and b.cpp it works correctly. So I'll just do that.

Comment: @EricSokolowsky - Nope, not with [just the code you show](https://wandbox.org/permlink/WICy7cqgVzKmmFSs). You did something wrong elsewhere most likely.

Comment: I tried your link using the default compiler (version 9.3.0) and indeed it worked. However, when I tried with gcc 9.2.0 on that site I do indeed get a linker error. But from what I understand, if all of the references to a::str are "extern" (these are just declarations), where is the definition?

Comment: @EricSokolowsky - Works for 9.1 too. Take note of the fact we have to add "b.cpp" as an additional argument manually. When you switched compilers that field was reset. Here it is working https://wandbox.org/permlink/uE6TPYaVCxOMvC0l

Comment: @EricSokolowsky - `extern` is "declaration only" when there is no initializer. An initializer turns it into a definition.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation. I have it all working now, using extern and const together. I also had to add -std=c++11 to get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add #include "a.cpp" into b.cpp.
Then you code will be correct, with extern definition in b and implementation in a.